# Pygame- Sprite set position with mouseclick

Tags: python, position, pygame, sprite

is there a possibilty to place a Sprite on the position, where i clicked?

```
class sprite_to_place(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_start_position , y_start_position ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("a_picture.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x_start_position # x where I clicked
        self.rect.y = y_start_position # y where I clicked
```

When I initialize the sprite_to_place I would use `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`.

And in the main loop I would place it with:

```
 if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    sprite_to_place_group.draw(gameDisplay)
```

But how can I get the position of the sprite, if I want to change its position with `def update()`? (I use `allsprites_group.update()`)

```
def update(self, startpos=(x_start_position, y_start_position)): # how can I tell the function where the sprite is on the map?
        self.pos = [startpos[0], startpos[1]]
        self.rect.x = round(self.pos[0] - cornerpoint[0], 0) #x
        self.rect.y = round(self.pos[1] - cornerpoint[1], 0) #y
```

If I would do it like in my example, it says that `x_start_position` and `y_start_position` are not defined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store the current position of the `Sprite` already in `self.rect`, so you don't need `x_start_position` and `y_start_position`.

If you want to store the original starting position you used when creating the `Sprite`, you'll have to create a member in the initializer:

```
#TODO: respect naming convention
class sprite_to_place(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # you can use a single parameter instead of two
    def __init__(self, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("a_picture.png")
        # you can pass the position directly to get_rect to set it's position
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        # I don't know if you actually need this
        self.start_pos = pos
```

Then in `update`:

```
def update(self): 
    # current position is self.rect.topleft
    # starting position is self.start_pos
    # to move the Sprite/Rect, you can also use the move functions
    self.rect.move_ip(10, 20) # moves the Sprite 10px vertically and 20px horizontally
```

Comment: Okay. But still it isn't possible to set the position of the sprite, where i clicked. I have to define where my Sprite is, before I can check the position of my mouse in the main loop.

Comment: So just set the position of your sprite in your mainloop to the mouse position. Where's the problem?

Comment: Well the problem is, that i want to create the  sprite on the screen with the mouseclick at the position of the mouse. So if I understood your solution correctly, the sprite has been placed on the map at position 'pos' and than it would be moved. Imagin placing a building in a strategy game, thats what I need. But thanks a lot for helping me :)

Comment: Why don't you just create your sprite with `a_variable = sprite_to_place(pygame.mouse.get_pos())`?

Comment: Because then it places the Sprite at the position my mouse was, when i clicked "run". So it wouldn't be updated.

Comment: My fault. I had to init the sprite in the main loop and put in a group and then draw it one the screen. Sry I'm quite a beginner. Thank you very much!